# Bootstrap multiple thumbnail carousel display width overlap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Could anyone please point out how I can get rid of the (what looks like 1px) overlap on the right side of the twitter multiple thumbnail Twitter Bootstrap carousel here > http://sxeo.co.uk/sxeo-services-seo-experts.htm in the best way?

Also I have put at the foot of the page presently the "older" and "newer" elements and as I do not own a mobile phone and have only been able to get a quick look in my Nieces apple mobile when she popped around earlier could anyone please tell me the best practice for this for mobiles please bearing in mind that the older or newer page may be any page on a present page (if that makes sense).

Could anyone help please?